# Install4j: How to create a desktop link that runs as minimized?

Tags: windows, shortcut, install4j

In install4j, with the "Add a desktop link" or "Create start menu entry", I can create a shortcut to my application.

In Windows, in the properties of the shortcut, I can choose to run it as a "Normal window", "Minimized" or "Maximized".

Is there a way to specify the shortcut to be run as minimized in install4j?

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.1.3, this is not supported by install4j.

Comment: OK, thanks.

Modifying a shortcut in Windows is simple for the user (it can be done in a few clicks) but really difficult to achieve programmatically...

Is there a way to get the path of the shortcut created by install4j to modify it with a script in an other action?

Comment: For the desktop: `new File(WinFileSystem.getSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.DESKTOP, false), "Link Name.url")`, for the start menu `new File(WinFileSystem.getSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.STARTMENU, true), "Folder/Link Name.url")`